# How to install sales forecast with full functionality for Odoo/OpenERP 8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have tried installing the `sale_forecast` module from external odoo link. However, I am not able to get the full functionality. When I open the module, I can't see the target data, goal data, achieved data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Odoo log file saying?
Usually when I am having troubles, the output from the log file puts me in the right direction.
Also, did you install the module? Because you say that you tried installing and not that you succeeded. Perhaps you tried to download a module that is not compatible with your Odoo version. What Odoo version are you running?

Why don't you try this? Navigate to your Odoo addons directory and download this Odoo 8 [module](https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/procurement_sale_forecast/). Then, log into your Odoo backend and from Local Modules/Addons click on Refresh Module List (i think the option was named like this, but I might be wrong). Then locate the newly added module and install it.

On another note, this could be a dependency error from which the module cannot be installed. Did you contact your host?
Usually, when I'm installing a module and encounter a problem, I am checking the log files and if I cannot solve the issue, I contact my [host](https://rosehosting.com). Thank god they are always helpful and patient with me. :)

This is just me guessing what could be the issue, since you didn't provide many details about your problem, but in most cases inspect your Odoo log file and use your host support to narrow down the possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you, for the time that you have spent for this, I am using odoo v8.. my odoo logs doesn't give me any errors, the module which you gave is installed, but in previous version, they had fields like target, goal..etc in sale_forecast.. Now it has been removed in odoo8, if there is any substitute modules available, please suggest.. Or suggestion on adding custom field for a module is also appreciative.